# Spring not a managed type, component and package scan pointing to correct package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot project pulling in a database config from an imported jar and also trying to wire up its own database config for a second database connection.  The first DB config inside the jar is marked with `@Primary`the second is not.

When i try to start up the project I get this error.

```
Not a managed type: class test.example.MyEntity
```

In my first DB config it is looking for an entirely different package, lets call it `com.example.test`, this is configured as such:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:/${app.execution.environment}/application.properties" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.test", entityManagerFactoryRef = "mysqlEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "mysqlTransactionManager")
public class MysqlHibernateConfig {
@Primary
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mysqlEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(mysqlDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.example.test" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        em.setJpaPropertyMap(hibernateProperties());

        return em;
    }

.... other relevant methods below for configuring DB
}
```

In my second DB config I point to an entirely different package for entities

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "test.example" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "myEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "myTransactionManager", basePackages = {
        "test.example" })
public class MyRepositoryConfig {

@Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean myEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(vspnetDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "test.example" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        em.setJpaPropertyMap(vspnetHibernateProperties());

        return em;
    }
}
```

I dont understand why it will not find and manage the beans under test.example, these entities look something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class MyEntity {

// column fields
}
```

And my config looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.test", "test.example"})
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

How can I get spring to manage these beans correctly and allow me to use these entities?

I checked all the managed beans and found my second entity manager showing up as well as my first so i know they are being wired up.  Not sure why they wont grab the right entities.

Full stack trace

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.2.RELEASE)

2017-07-21 10:06:57,989 INFO  application - Starting application on MacBook-Pro-2.local with PID 5694 (targetclasses started by stevmc in /Users/stevmc/git/oos-admin-ng2) [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:06:57,992 INFO  application - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:06:58,039 INFO  AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@12b0404f: startup date [Fri Jul 21 10:06:58 PDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:06:59,564 INFO  AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:06:59,728 INFO  PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b8cd37e5] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying) [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:06:59,785 INFO  AnnotationActionEndpointMapping - Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0] [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:06:59,825 INFO  PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$143572e6] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying) [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:06:59,954 INFO  PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'oos-member-ecom-api-dep-config' of type [com.example.oos.member.config.EcomEligibilityServiceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$20a01c0c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying) [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:00,253 INFO  TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http) [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:00,261 INFO  StandardService - Starting service Tomcat [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:00,261 INFO  StandardEngine - Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11 [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:00,335 INFO  [/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:00,335 INFO  ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2300 ms [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:00,716 INFO  FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'metricsFilter' to: [/*] [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:00,716 INFO  FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*] [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:00,716 INFO  FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*] [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:00,716 INFO  FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*] [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:00,716 INFO  FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*] [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:00,716 INFO  FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'corsFilter' to: [/*] [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:00,716 INFO  FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*] [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:00,716 INFO  FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*] [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:00,716 INFO  ServletRegistrationBean - Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/] [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:00,717 INFO  ServletRegistrationBean - Mapping servlet: 'messageDispatcherServlet' to [/services/*] [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:00,756 INFO  DriverManagerDataSource - Loaded JDBC driver: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:00,835 INFO  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:00,844 INFO  LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...] [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:00,885 INFO  Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final} [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:00,887 INFO  Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:00,887 INFO  Environment - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:00,913 INFO  Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final} [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:01,035 INFO  Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:01,072 INFO  LobCreatorBuilderImpl - HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4 [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:01,250 WARN  RootClass - HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): test.steven.EmployeeGroupEntity$EmployeeGroupId [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:01,250 WARN  RootClass - HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): test.steven.EmployeeGroupEntity$EmployeeGroupId [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:01,420 INFO  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:01,448 INFO  DriverManagerDataSource - Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:01,526 INFO  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:01,527 INFO  LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...] [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:01,697 INFO  Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:01,927 WARN  EntityManagerFactoryRegistry - HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (default) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name' [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:01,927 INFO  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:02,309 WARN  AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController' defined in file [targetclasses/com/example/oos/admin/controller/UserController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeService' defined in file [targetclasses/com/example/oos/admin/service/EmployeeService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class test.steven.EmployeeEntity [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:02,309 INFO  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:02,310 INFO  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:02,311 INFO  StandardService - Stopping service Tomcat [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:02,321 INFO  AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. [tx-id=] 
2017-07-21 10:07:02,329 ERROR SpringApplication - Application startup failed [tx-id=] 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController' defined in file [targetclasses/com/example/oos/admin/controller/UserController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeService' defined in file [targetclasses/com/example/oos/admin/service/EmployeeService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class test.steven.EmployeeEntity
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
    at com.example.oos.admin.application.main(application.java:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeService' defined in file [targetclasses/com/example/oos/admin/service/EmployeeService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class test.steven.EmployeeEntity
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class test.steven.EmployeeEntity
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class test.steven.EmployeeEntity
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:70)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:153)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:100)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:199)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 44 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What do you want as a result? Two EMs controlling separate sets of entities or one EM controlling all of them?

Comment: Two EM's controlling separate sets of entities

Comment: So which EM is throwing that exception? also please include the full stack trace.

Comment: The first EM is connecting to all entities.  I want the item test.steven.EmployeeEntity to be managed by my sedond EM. Stacktrace added.

Comment: Another note, if i put both sets of entities under the same package, then the first EM tries to access the second EM's entities.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this @wondergoat77 ? Currently facing the same issue.

Comment: @acidnbass I actually never did sorry. The project i was working on for this ended up fizzling out so i never had to solve this.  I am assuming I will approach it again.  If i solve this I will update this post with a solution and tag you in it.